# Receiving "WSManNetworkFailureDetected" error on a particular domain pc I'm running my script on

Tags: powershell

This script, as with all scripts I use to support domain machines, is being run in our server through RDS man. Same location where all AD machines and user accounts are being managed:

```
$id = Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $ComputerName -TaskPath '*EnterpriseMgmt*' | select -Property 'TaskPath' -First 1
```

I am essentially getting a particular entry in the Task Schedular and have been able to do this on several other remote pcs although this machine seems to be throwing the following error:

```
WARNING: MKC-02707: [WSManNetworkFailureDetected] The network connection to MKC-02707 has been interrupted. Attempting to reconnect for up to 4 minutes... 
WARNING: MKC-02707: [WSManConnectionRetryAttempt] Attempting to reconnect to MKC-02707 ... 
WARNING: MKC-02707: [WSManConnectionRetryAttempt] Attempting to reconnect to MKC-02707 ...
```

The pc in question is on, responding to ping request and enabled in Active Directory. I can't think of why it is doing this or whether there is something in the script that will fix this.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have a feeling this has something to do with `-CimSession`.

Comment: Just cause you can ping a machine, doesn't mean you can connect to to it. I would try to make sure PowerShell remoting is enabled, or use a separate protocol to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

To continue from the above, I left this one overnight and its working now. Not sure why but if people still want to provide troubleshooting methods for future use I'm sure that would be helpful.